# How to get and show the best selling products in magento 2

Tags: frontend, magento2.2.6, best-seller

I wish to **show best selling products** in homepage.Please provide me a solution to **get best selling products** and display in home page.
Thanks

Comment: follow this http://www.webetutorial.com/blog/display-best-selling-products-homepage-magento2/ or this one https://bsscommerce.com/confluence/how-to-get-best-selling-products-in-magento2/

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1: Create a block file**

```
namespace {custom namespace}\Block;

class BestSeller extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    protected $_collectionFactory;
   public function __construct(
       \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
      \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
               array $data = []
   ) {

       $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
             parent::__construct($context, $data);
   }


public function getBestSellerData(){

$bestSellerProdcutCollection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()
                    ->setModel('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')
                    ->setPeriod('month') //you can add period daily,yearly
                   ;

       return $bestSellerProdcutCollection;
   }
}
```

**Step 2: Show Output**

Getting collection in phtml file from block.

```
    <?php
        $bestSeller =  $block->getBestSellerData(); ?>
        <h1>Best Seller Collection.....</h1>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($bestSeller as $product) {
                ?>
                <li><?php  echo $product->getProductName();?>--<?php  echo $product->getQtyOrdered();?></li>
            <?php } ?>
</ul> 
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: how can we get today, last month, last 3 month best seller product using this code? –